# How can I call this controller in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, phpstorm

I´m totally new to php and Codeigniter. Below you can see my first controller that I wrote.

```
namespace App\Controllers;

class FirstController extends BaseController{

    public function viewExample(){
        $a = 'example';
        echo $a;
    }
}
```

I use xampp and tried to call the function with the URL:

http://localhost/project-name/public/FirstController/viewExample/

But the page can´t be found...

phpStorm declares the controller and the function as unused elements.

Comment: `http://localhost/project-name/public` looks like your webserver isn't set up quite right, `public/` should be your project's "DocumentRoot" - you most likely don't have a virtual host set up (or you can use `php spark serve` to run a development server). [Running Your App](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/running.html#) for more info

Comment: Did you add a route for this controller and method in `app/Config/Routes.php` ? Also, running the project using `http://localhost/project-name/public` should work fine when using xampp, you don't necessarily need to use spark.

Answer (score 1):

In CodeIgniter4 you have to [define your routes](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html#adding-routing-rules) in `app/Config/Routes.php`.
If you need auto routing, you have to set `$autoRoute = true;` in `Routes.php`.

Codeigniter provide a good [documention](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/intro/index.html) to start from scratch.

[Read more about auto routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html#auto-routing-improved)